# How to access files in folder on iphone 6 IOS 14.8

Tags: itunes, file-transfer

I recently installed an app on my phone that converts photos to PDF.  The PDF is too big to email to my Windows10 PC so I saved it in a folder on my phone and would like to access it via iTunes or logging into icloud.com, but I can't find the folder or file.

Any suggestions for how to do so?

Note: I can see the PDF on my phone in "Files" (I guess that's the app?" but there's not Files app in iTunes.

Comment: Can you find it in the Files app? If so, where?

Comment: I can see the PDF on my phone in "Files" (I guess that's the app?" but there's not Files app in iTunes

Comment: If it's in the "On My iPhone" section, you can drag and drop it into the iCloud section, then it will be visible on iCloud.com That's the easiest option.